# Understanding Matplotlib's quiver plotting

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand how `plt.quiver()` works. My issue is as follows:

I plot a simple vector `(1,1)` as such:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.quiver(0,0, 1, 1, units = 'xy', scale = 1)
plt.xticks(range(-5,6))
plt.yticks(range(-5,6))
plt.grid()
```

I would expect the arrow to go from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)`, but the result is slightly off from that:[image: vector 1,1]

Similarly, I try and plot an arrow for vector `(0,3)` and the resulting arrow seems to be for vector `(0,3.5)`...

[image]

My assumption is that this has something to do with the *kwargs*  `'units'`, `'scale'`, `'angles'`, & `'scale_units'`. I've read the docs on them but don't fully understand how they work. A sunday school explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about, you try them, plot them together with the plots you already have and report remaining questions?

Comment: used: `ax.quiver((0,0), (0,0), (1,0), (1,3), units = 'xy', scale = 1)` and got same result (just combined). ie a chart with 1 arrow going from 0,0 to 0,3.5(ish) and another arrow going from 0,0 to aprox 0.9,1.2

Comment: I guess then you just answered your question :)

Comment: ... How so? Why don't the go to expected coords, i.e. The ones I supplied?

Comment: See the answer below about the aspect ratio. Then your problem is solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you adjust the aspect ratio of the figure to 1, the vectors are displayed to proper scale:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.quiver((0,0), (0,0), (1,0), (1,3), units = 'xy', scale = 1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xticks(range(-5,6))
plt.yticks(range(-5,6))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.quiver(0,0, 1, 1,angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale = 1)
plt.xticks(range(-5,6))
plt.yticks(range(-5,6))
plt.grid()
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the output]

Just remember that the first two arguments of `quiver` are the x and y coordinates of the tail of the vector, the next two are the lengths of the vector along x and y direction respectively. `angle='xy'` makes the arrow point from tail of the vector to its tip.

You can find out more about matplotlib.quiver at http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver