# Python quiver angles issue: What is the difference between angles="uv" and angles="xy"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a vector field that I want to plot correctly. When I use quiver as is, it seems to be outputting the correct plot:

[image]

However, if I follow the guidelines to have quiver scale and show the correct angles of the vectors, as given here [Understanding Matplotlib's quiver plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534381/understanding-matplotlibs-quiver-plotting), then I don't get the same plot:

[image]

Does anybody knows why?

*Here is the code:*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.array([[0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ]])    

yy = np.array([[-200. , -200. , -200. , -200. , -200. , -200. ],
   [-144.6, -144.6, -144.6, -144.6, -144.6, -144.6],
   [ -89.2,  -89.2,  -89.2,  -89.2,  -89.2,  -89.2],
   [ -33.8,  -33.8,  -33.8,  -33.8,  -33.8,  -33.8],
   [  21.6,   21.6,   21.6,   21.6,   21.6,   21.6],
   [  77. ,   77. ,   77. ,   77. ,   77. ,   77. ]])


dx = np.array([[ 6.18291908e-09,  3.70076924e-06,  3.42538903e-06,
            -4.38426006e-07, -2.55227640e-06,  6.18291908e-09],
           [ 2.17018678e-06,  2.51500956e-04,  1.73477082e-04,
            -1.23855846e-04, -2.29881121e-04,  2.17018678e-06],
           [ 2.44470726e-05,  3.79715107e-03,  2.49497711e-03,
            -2.05506466e-03, -3.60106480e-03,  2.44470726e-05],
           [ 2.87699956e-04,  3.56327893e-02,  2.23694354e-02,
            -2.17573718e-02, -3.50990203e-02,  2.87699956e-04],
           [ 2.13917741e-03,  1.07630739e-01,  1.09098114e-01,
            -1.73049517e-01, -1.15168685e-01,  2.13917741e-03],
           [ 3.13827774e-04, -3.87236380e-02, -4.33945841e-02,
             7.12401001e-02,  3.91662321e-02,  3.13827774e-04]])

dy = np.array([[0.24105279, 0.24104844, 0.24104251, 0.24104319, 0.24104954,
        0.24105279],
       [0.2409212 , 0.24103392, 0.24123878, 0.24125286, 0.24105669,
        0.2409212 ],
       [0.23870441, 0.24127457, 0.24563927, 0.24579267, 0.24151955,
        0.23870441],
       [0.21110992, 0.24513396, 0.30153966, 0.30228133, 0.24619877,
        0.21110992],
       [0.07941149, 0.14922776, 0.70945221, 0.67353021, 0.12818932,
        0.07941149],
       [0.07717276, 0.04937775, 0.18100361, 0.16734886, 0.03621946,
        0.07717276]])

# PLOT 1 (Correct one)

plt.figure(1, dpi = 300)
plt.quiver(xx, yy, dx, dy)
plt.title("Plot 1")
plt.show()

# PLOT 2 (Something is wrong her)
# Inspiration from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534381/understanding-matplotlibs-quiver-plotting

plt.figure(2, dpi = 300)
plt.quiver(xx, yy, dx, dy, angles="xy", scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.title("Plot 2")
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**
Please have a look at the dx, dy data: The `dx` data is smaller than the `dy` data, therefore, the vectors should always point upward and not sight-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) I would say that the difference can be explained as follows:

If you are using `angles = 'uv'` the arrow aspect ratio is set to one which is the default setting while when you use `angles = 'xy'` you really print the vector that is pointing from (x,y) to (x+u,y+v). In other words the vectors in plot 2 are just very badly scaled but the function does what it is supposed to do.

In `uv`-mode the arrows axis is independent from the x,y axis ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793436/get-coordinates-of-quiver-arrow-tip-and-bottom-when-plotting-in-uv-mode)). The arrows aspect ratio which is the ratio from width of the arrow to it´s height is set to one.

In your question you said that you want to plot the vector field correctly and therfore i think you want to use `xy`-mode. I tried a few settings maybe you are happy with that.

```
plt.quiver(xx, yy, dx, dy, angles="xy",scale = 8,width = 0.004)
```

[image: Using angles=xy]

Another option for drawing vector fields would be using `streamplot`, which may produce a result that meets your demand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "arrow aspect ratio"? Also, how would you fix the scaling on the second plot?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated answer! This already clarifies a few things. However, please have a look at the dx, dy data: As you can see the dx data is smaller than the dy data, therefore, the vectors should always point upward and not sightwaise.

Comment: I admit on first sight you are right but you are missing the scaling of the x and y axis. For instance let´s take the one long arrow pointing to the right at the position (0.4, 21.6). It has a dx and dy tuple of (0.1, 0.7). So due to the scaling of the x-axis you can see the 0.1 in that direction as a very large distance but the 0.7 on the y-axis seems to be almost zero because on the y-axis the scaling is much different. 
You would get what you expected in your comment above if the scaling of x and y axis would be equal. Please let me if that is not clear to you.

Comment: That was a very good explanation! Thank you very much. So in essence, the plot aspect ratio would need to be proportional to the x, and y values (on the axis) for the vector plot to be displayed perfectly, but then one would not recognize it anymore. I see... 


Could you maybe try to uncouple the scaling of the axis and the actual vector length? Maybe one could take the vector data, and re-scale everything between 0 and 1 (max vector data) and plot it on a grid where x and y go from [0,1] as well, and finally overwrite the x and y-axis ticks to display the actual min/max?

Comment: You´re welcome. Basically the uncoupling is done in `uv`-mode. Do you really need to plot the y values from -200 to 50? Or could you maybe select for the x values a larger distance? Otherwise i would say that the data is as it is and a physically correct visualization would force you to use `xy`-mode. Otherwise the picture gives you kind of a wrong feeling of what is going on in the vector field.

Comment: True, but physically correct would also mean to have the same scale on x and y, which would then stretch the picture immensely and not be able to see anything anymore.

Comment: That is also true. Basically the problem is that you have a lot of very short arrows and two that are quite long. So what i would maybe do is to stretch all shorter vectors a little bit just that you can see them. The information that is transported by the picture is how the vector flow is going. I think nobody cares if you scaled some arrows a little so that they get visible.