# Matplotlib generating the wrong vector

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this simple code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
X = [0] 
Y = [0] 
U = [4]   
V = [1]   
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, color='b', units='xy', scale=1) 
plt.title('Single Vector') 
plt.xlim(-2, 5) 
plt.ylim(-2, 2.5) 
plt.grid() 
plt.show()
```

But the output is definitely wrong, as you can see below. How can I fix this?

[image: output]

Comment: Getting rid of `units='xy'` solves it for me and shows an arrow attached to (0, 0) and pointing in the direction of (4, 1) as desired, but I don't know the explanation. https://i.imgur.com/kNANvxN.png

Comment: If you mean with wrong that the arrow head doesn't end exactly at [4,1] in your screenshot - when I run your code it exactly ends there. For sure that info doesn't solve your problem, but maybe a hint that it's not code related. Can you try it in a different terminal / IDE / jupyter notebook to double check?

Comment: @MagnusO_O Resize the window / change the limits and you will see the arrow end move around. That being said, your comment raised a good point: OP might confuse quivers and [arrows](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html). `plt.arrow(0, 0, 4, 1)` would make  the arrow end touch (4, 1) regardless of zoom level.

Comment: Found [Understanding Matplotlib's quiver plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534381/understanding-matplotlibs-quiver-plotting), with ... `fig = plt.figure()`, `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`, `ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, color='b', units='xy', scale=1)`, `plt.axis('equal')` ... the window opens with the correct scaling and arrow head end. Anyway as @Guimoute pointed out it still changes with changing the window aspect ratio (hadn't tried that before).